# Lost some files in a Git versioned project and could only recover them... in a fork on Github

Tags: git, github, fork

Lately I realized that I had lost some files in one of my projects hosted on Github, [jquery.transition.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js). I searched in the commit history to try to find when and how that happened but couldn't find any related commits.

Then I looked at its network graph on Github and found all of the commits and files in someone else's fork: https://github.com/ammonkc/jquery.transition.js/tree/gh-pages

I'm wondering how this is possible. Could it be that I inadvertently deleted the gh-pages branch and overwrote it? Shouldn't that appear in the commit history?

Comment: How did you search the history?  Did you use `git log -- that/missing/file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What usually *can* happen  is:

- a branch deleted or a forced push where those commit are no longer referenced
- a fork done prior to that event which still referenced said commits

Such a push (with a rewritten history without those commits) can only happen if it is "forced" (`push --force`), but wouldn't leave a trace in the visible history (since the commits have been rewritten).
Even in the worst case scenario, the lost commits are still referenced in the [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html), which you can:

- ask for at the GitHub support (they can create a branch referencing said lost commits).
- or (as repo owner) **query the GitHub events API**:
  See "[Does GitHub remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)"