# How to recover from the "git push -f origin HEAD^:master" command?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I was searching for a way to remove my last GitHub commit and found this command on:

[How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/)

It worked. The problem is that I accidentally did it to the wrong repository.

I read in comments that commit is not really deleted, but

> "...this only moves the branch pointer."

How can I recover from this command and revert to the last commit?

Comment: `git reflog` may help if you were on that commit recently in your repo

Comment: umm, `git push -f github <correct_state>:<required_branch>` ?

Comment: using 'git reflog' returned HEAD@{0} : clone : "path/to/git". Nothing changed in the repository.

Comment: the branch is 'master' but what do you mean by <correct_state>?

Comment: actually, when using 'git reflog' the first value(hash) is the same as currently in the last commit on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub has an hidden reflog: the [GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/).

See "[Does github remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)"

By curling the `https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/events`, and looking for push events, you can find the commit pushed to master before your own, and push again that commit, provided you had a local clone of that repo.

Comment: Is there any chance to recover the commit if I don't have a local clone of that repo?

Comment: @Boykodev is there anyone else who has clone that repo? He or she can simply push back his/her current HEAD in a `git push --force`.