# Repository commit count wrong

Tags: git, github

Repo: [sumitridhal/n-th-digit-of-e](https://github.com/sumitridhal/n-th-digit-of-e)

Count shown in github profile and commit count in repository not matching.
Due to this some of latest commits are missing from repository.
Is there any way i can retrieve all my commits?

[image: repo]

Comment: Did you reset or rebase anything?

Comment: @melpomene Yes i did. Is any way to recover the changes?

Comment: What do you actually want the outcome to be? Why does it matter that the counts are different?

Comment: @jonrsharpe some of latest commits are missing from repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you rebase and then force push, you need to try and restore the previous master HEAD which was overwritten by the new (and shorter) history.

Check [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): you should see your old commit before rebase.
Or See "[Does github remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)": you can query the push events to get back an old commit that way.

In both instances, you can at least create a branch based on that commit (either local branch on your PC, or a remote branch directly through the GitHub web interface), in order to see if you get back your history.
The number will still be off, but at least your missing commits will be there, and you can try again to cherry-pick/order them as you want.