# Git remote branch got deleted, how to resync local changes with new branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I got a remote branch as **develop_1** which I was using. All my local code changes were committed to it but my lead has accidentally deleted that remote branch.

I have all those code changes in my local system. Now I want to push all those changes back to that same Git repository in a new remote branch, say **develop_2**.

How can I create a new branch, sync my local changes and push it to remote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within your local branch **develop_1** you could simply create the new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b develop_2
```

Push your changes and then to keep your local repo in sync by running:

```
$ git fetch -p
```

The `-p` is for `prune` deleting local branches, in this case, the old **develop_1** that don't exist in the remote anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> but my lead has accidentally deleted that remote branch

If this is on GitHub, you can get back the SHA1 of the remote branch with the "**poor man's reflog**", aka the **push events** ([GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/)).
See "[Does github remember commit IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309)": look for any recent push events on the `master` branch: [you can then fetch that commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872590/6309) (and its associated history) back to your local repo.
If not, the [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) will have a look in order to restore your previous content.

A forced push is then needed to restore the same history on the remote side.

But even simpler, if your local changes were done on top of what was already pushed, you don't have to create a new branch: push your existing branch back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forked the remote repo and then cloned it on your local?

If you have code changes on your local branch say `local_dev` and you want to push to `develop_2` then command be like:

`git push -u origin local_dev:develop_2` then raise the pull request against the main repo.

If you have direct access to remote repo then directly push the changes to the remote. No need to raise the pull request