# Accidentally deleted all github branches

Tags: github

There was a file with sensitive information that i accidentally uploaded to github so i tried to remove it by following the steps from this
https://github.com/IBM/BluePic/wiki/Using-BFG-Repo-Cleaner-tool-to-remove-sensitive-files-from-your-git-repo
When i ran the last part it deleted all my branches except for the main branch and my current working branch.

I tried to reflog but there wasn't a commit that included the deletion of the branches.

Answer (score 0):

All the steps are done on a local clone of a repo.

If the end result is somehow botched, you could simply re-clone the repo, and try again.

Comment: thats what i thought too. i didnt even push it or anything but when i ran it the terminal just showed the name of branches and [deleted] beside them.

Comment: You can easily visit github.com to confirm whether the branches are still there.

Comment: I have and its not there.
also i just realized i put the wrong link up. I'll edit the post.
Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @XiaoNingEr If the branches are no longer on your remote GitHub repo, chances are... they are still there (on the remote repo): see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317744/6309 and its associated links.