# Git: How to reset devel to master?

Tags: git, branch, git-reset

I have branches `master` and `devel`.

I want to save `devel` somewhere for the (unlikely) case if I will need to restore the information in it and afterward to reset the head of `devel` to the head of `master` (without modifying `master`).

Is the following the right way to do this?

```
git checkout devel
git checkout -b devel-save
git push
git checkout devel
git reset --hard master
git push --force
```

Comment: You can also just push the master branch commit to the remote with the “devel” name. Same can be done for saving the specific branch (although I might use a tag). Then update to the remote branch locally to sync as needed, and/or nuke the local if not useful currently. Ensure to communicate a force-update of a mainline branch.

Comment: @user2864740 But is my way right. Can I be sure of no data loss if I do this as I described in the question?

Comment: Git will not "lose data" as long as there is a branch (or tag) that points to a commit - that commit and all ancestors will persist. This is fulfilled for *devel* via `devel-save`.

Comment: I might do it more like this: `git tag devel-save devel; git checkout devel; git reset --hard master; git push --force`. Don't forget to push the `devel-save` tag/commit if wishing it ensure it is available remotely.

Comment: Also, Git keeps around a large history (see the `reflog`), so even an unnamed commit will not be *really* lost until Git does a 'garbage compaction' and that commit is removed. By default even such orphaned commits will hang around for a month. Deleting a git repo, or having such corrupted by other means, is outside the control of git.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I be sure of no data loss if I do this as I described in the question?

No data will be lost.

You can also directly push develop: `git push develop:old-develop`, then reset `master` and force push.
The [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) mentioned in the comment.
On GitHub side, you have a [poor man reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309) which allows you to get back past deleted history. But in your case, that history will be visible and reference (under a new branch name).

Comment: You have not answered if *my* way may lead to any data loss.

Comment: I thought I had, with the first sentence of my answer.