# Retrieve the previous state of the forked repository

Tags: git, github

I accidentally pushed the wrong commit, which was the first commit, to the main branch of the forked repository.

Since that forked repository has a lot of directories, I always downloaded only directories that I would work on at the time on my local machine.  Then, I created or modified files.

Before I pushed the first commit(the wrong one), I always had uploaded those new files or modified files on the GitHub repository using the GitHub web UI.  I'd never committed to Git at that moment.

Once I uploaded those files, I deleted them from my local machine.

Then, I committed a file to Git and pushed it to GitHub(used the following command `git push -f`)...now there is only one file in the repository.

I wanted to undo this and get back the forked repository with all files I uploaded.
(I did undo the commit with `git update-ref -d HEAD` command, but there's no change on GitHub of course.)

I hope this explains my situation well enough, and please help me out.

**(I thought I needed to ask the GitHub Support team and did, but still can't solve it yet...)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the GitHub [poor man's reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309) and query the [GitHub Events API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#events) in order to get the most recent "previous" commit.

```
curl -u <username> https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/events
```

(replace `:owner` and `:repo` by your GitHub login and repository name)

From there, you can create a branch (on GitHub side) based on that commit:

```
curl -u <github-username> -X POST -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/<new-branch-name>", "sha":"<sha-from-step-1>"}' https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs
```

You can the fetch from origin, and locally reset your main branch to said "rescue" branch

```
git switch -C main origin/<new-branch-name>
git push -f
```

Note: you might need to add a [personal access token when using `curl`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#using-personal-access-tokens)

```
curl -i -u username:$token https://api.github.com/...
```

See [Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I could get SHA, but after the following command 
`curl -u <github-username> -X POST -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/<new-branch-name>", "sha":"<sha-from-step-1>"}' https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs
`

I got this one:
`{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#create-a-reference"
}`

does this mean it's impossible to retrieve the previous one anymore?

Comment: @Kaho Did you replace the various parameters between `<...>`, like `<sha-from-step-1>`? And `;owner/:repo` as well?

Comment: Yes, I changed `<github-username>`, `<new-branch-name>`, `<sha-from-step-1>`, and `:owner`, `:repo` to mine.  is this because I force-pushed? I contacted the GitHub support team and they said they cannot revert the repository since they don't keep snapshots of the repository.  I'm wondering if there are some changes...

Comment: @Kaho No, the force push does not matter, unless you have done it more than 90 days ago. It should work. Check https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-reference and try to replace `<github-username>` with a PAT (personal access token) and add (as in the documentation example) `-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"`.

Comment: I did it! I made a mistake with the password...I'd kept putting the password for my computer or GitHub.  When putting a PAT, it worked fine.
You are a lifesaver, or saviour rather!