# git push -f without pulling first now full of regret

Tags: git, push, revert

I was on a branch where my colleague pushed a couple of commits since my last pull.

Now, git told me to pull first.
I however insisted to push my changes, so I added a `--force` flag.

Now this branch has my commit as `HEAD` with no way for me to pull the commits from my colleague, or restore the state before my push.

Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: If your colleague still has his commit, the simplest way is for him to force push

Comment: BTW, this sort of thing is IMHO a good reason to get in the habit of using `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force`, even when you're absolutely sure that nobody else changed anything on the remote.

Comment: @Hasturkun Good point. I have detailed that in "[`git push --force-with-lease` vs. `--force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your colleague is not available to force push their own branch, you can check with the Git hosting server you are pushing to.

- an on-premise server might have an admin able to get the `reflog` of the target remote repository, getting back the past reference of the branch overridden.
- a GitHub repository would allow you to [query push events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309), getting the past reference that way

The [OP donjonson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12689813/donjonson) confirms the simplest option in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927550/git-push-f-without-pulling-first-now-full-of-regret/69929297#comment123637730_69929297):

> At the end of the day, my colleague answered my calls and that solved the problem.

Comment: Hey, yeah at the end of the day my colleague answered my calls and that solved the problem, thanks a lot:)

Comment: @donjonson Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.